# Carto DB - problem with animated heat maps

Tags: carto, heat-map

I want to create a map that shows multiple points changing over time. So the animated heat map seems perfect. To explain why it isn't working I'll need to tell you a bit about the data I'm mapping.

I'm mapping the places people blog about when they blog about climate change. I used a geo-extractor to identify thousands of locations in thousands of blog posts. So for example I can tell you that Paris was mentioned so many hundred times in blogs about climate change during 2015, but hardly at all in 2013. (And all kinds of other interesting things). The time data is in years. I've got 12 years worth of data.

Now the problem. If I set the animated heat map "steps" number to 16 then some years fall entirely within one "step" while other years are spread over two. This means that when the map is animated it doesn't really show you the year to year progression. What I need is for each year to be one step in the animation. And to make sure all my 2014 data points light up only in 2014 and all my 2015 data points like up only in 2015.

Having played around with the various options I can't work out how to do this. But it seems like something well within the capabilities of the Torque heat map. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

note: *Pasting here [answer provided](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cartodb/vRn3g4R8SeE/-mPkbbX9FwAJ) at google group*

Torque accepts numeric fields so you can try to assign all your points to an integer say 2010 = 1, 2011 = 2, etc and then set the same number of steps of the domain of that integer both on the number of frames and the duration, the latest that can be a multiply of the number of frames if you don't want them to be of one second. You can use the extract [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) to get that integer.